# xcode when i run program on iphone 6 screen looks iphone 5 How to fix this?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have a problem with an app that i created, it's developed based on a 4 inch layout, a week ago i've tested it on Iphone 6 Simulator it looked great, today when i wanted to take screenshots, the screen looks like iphone 5 screen. I've checked and unchecked AutoLayout, and size classes was disabled from the begging.

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: Check you have launch images which are the right size. Also worth deleting the app from the simulator and then running.

Comment: but i didn't have launch images before, and it worked before..

Comment: Have you updated to xcode 6.3 in last few weeks? Either way try deleting the app first by clicking and holding down on the app icon in the simulator as you would on a real device and then rerun.

Comment: Yes my xcode is up to date, i've deleted the app from simulator, and did put launch images, and still the same.

Answer (score 0):

For your launch images, make sure in the inspector you have iOS 8 sizes checked. Once you put the launch images for those, the app will automatically adjust and stop scaling.